# Retrieve subinputs related to a parent input with php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I need a form where I dynamically add SERVICES to a contract, and for every SERVICE I can add 1 or more (or none!) sub-inputs.

For example i create:

```
SERVICE-1
```

with sub-inputs:

`SELECT: "Option 1" QTY: "10"`

`SELECT: "Option 2" QTY: "20"`

`SELECT: "Option 3" QTY: "30"`

```
SERVICE-2
```

with sub-inputs:

`SELECT: "Option 1" QTY: "40"`

```
SERVICE-3
```

with sub-inputs:

`SELECT: "Option 4" QTY: "15"`

`SELECT: "Option 3" QTY: "10"`

and

```
SERVICE-4
```

without sub-inputs

I've edited this jsfiddle to my example: http://jsfiddle.net/WhaBx/22/
but i don't know how to pass those grouped input to get inside `insert.php` page an array like:

```
$services =

    [0] => array(
     "name" => "SERVICE-1",
     "attributes" => array(
        [0] => array(
           "attribute" => "Option 1",
           "qty" => 10        
        ),
        [1] => array(
           "attribute" => "Option 2",
           "qty" => 20        
        ),
        [2] => array(
           "attribute" => "Option 3",
           "qty" => 30        
        )
     )
    ),
    [1] => array(
     "name" => "SERVICE-2",
     "attributes" => array(
        [0] => array(
           "attribute" => "Option 1",
           "qty" => 40        
        )
     )
    ),
    [2] => array(
     "name" => "SERVICE-3",
     "attributes" => array(
        [0] => array(
           "attribute" => "Option 4",
           "qty" => 15        
        ),
        [1] => array(
           "attribute" => "Option 3",
           "qty" => 10        
        )
     )
    ),
    [3] => array(
     "name" => "SERVICE-4",
     "attributes" => array(

     )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the name of the input field based on the resulting array you want to have.

This would look similar to this:

Service:
`<input name="service[0][name]" value="Service-1" type="hidden">`
`<input name="service[1][name]" value="Service-2" type="hidden">`

Attributes:
`<input name="service[0][attributes][][attribute]" value="Option 1" type="hidden">`
`<input name="service[0][attributes][][qty]" value="10" type="hidden">`
`<input name="service[0][attributes][][attribute]" value="Option 2" type="hidden">`
`<input name="service[0][attributes][][qty]" value="20" type="hidden">`

Of course you wouldn't use hidden fields put the input type you need. This is just an example on how the name would correspond to the value you want to have.

Comment: I don't know how to manage indexes of eventually delete of a service, for example if I insert 3 services i've 0,1,2 indexes...then i delete second service (with index=1), then I insert a new service...in this case new index is 2 that already exist: 0,2,2

Comment: Add a variable to your javascript which holds the latest id. Increase it when you add a service but don't decrease it. Like this it is no problem if you delete an entry. Also it is faster than always counting how many elements with a specific id or class are present in the DOM